# Implementation of gradient descent blowing up to infinity?

Tags: python, linear-regression

This is how I generated the training data for my Linear Regression.

```
!pip install grapher, numpy

from grapher import Grapher
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Secret: y = 3x + 4

# x, y = [float(row[0]) for row in rows], [float(row[5]) for row in rows]

x, y = [a for a in range(-20, 20)], [3*a + 4 for a in range(-20, 20)]


g = Grapher(['3*x + 4'], title="y = 3x+4")
plt.scatter(x, y)
g.plot()
```

[image]

Then, I tried gradient descent on a simple quadratic function (x - 7)^2

```
def n(x):
    return (x-7)**2

cur_x = 0
lr = 0.001
ittr = 10000
n = 0
prev_x = -1
max_precision = 0.0000001
precision = 1

while n < ittr and precision > max_precision:
    prev_x = cur_x

    cur_x = cur_x - lr * (2*(cur_x - 7))
    precision = abs(prev_x - cur_x)

    n+=1
    if n%100 == 0:
        print(n, ':')
        print(cur_x)
        print()

print(cur_x)
```

And this works perfectly.

Then I made a Linear Regression class to make the same thing happen.

```
class LinearRegression:
    def __init__(self, X, Y):
        self.X = X
        self.Y = Y
        self.m = 1
        self.c = 0
        self.learning_rate = 0.01
        self.max_precision = 0.000001
        self.itter = 10000

    def h(self, x, m, c):
        return m * x + c

    def J(self, m, c):
        loss = 0
        for x in self.X:
            loss += (self.h(x, m, c) - self.Y[self.X.index(x)])**2

        return loss/2

    def calc_loss(self):
        return self.J(self.m, self.c)

    def guess_answer(self, step=1):
        losses = []
        mcvalues = []
        for m in np.arange(-10, 10, step):
            for c in np.arange(-10, 10, step):
                mcvalues.append((m, c))
                losses.append(self.J(m, c))

        minloss = sorted(losses)[0]
        return mcvalues[losses.index(minloss)]

    def gradient_decent(self):
        print('Orignal: ', self.m, self.c)

        nm = 0
        nc = 0

        prev_m = 0
        perv_c = -1

        mprecision = 1
        cprecision = 1

        while nm < self.itter and mprecision > self.max_precision:
            prev_m = self.m
            nm += 1

            self.m = self.m - self.learning_rate * sum([(self.h(x, self.m, self.c) - self.Y[self.X.index(x)])*x for x in self.X])
            mprecision = abs(self.m - prev_m)

        return self.m, self.c

    def graph_loss(self):
        plt.scatter(0, self.J(0))
        print(self.J(0))
        plt.plot(self.X, [self.J(x) for x in self.X])

    def check_loss(self):
        plt.plot([m for m in range(-20, 20)], [self.J(m, 0) for m in range(-20, 20)])
        x1 = 10
        y1 = self.J(x1, 0)
        l = sum([(self.h(x, x1, self.c) - self.Y[self.X.index(x)])*x for x in self.X])
        print(l)
        plt.plot([m for m in range(-20, 20)], [(l*(m - x1)) + y1 for m in range(-20, 20)])
        plt.scatter([x1], [y1])

LinearRegression(x, y).gradient_decent()
```

Output is

```
Orignal:  1 0
(nan, 0)
```

Then I tried graphing my Loss Function (J(m, c)) and tried to use its derivative to see if it actuallly gives slope. I was in a suspection that I have messed up my d(J(m, c))/dm

After running `LinearRegression(x, y).check_loss()`

I get this graph

[image]

It is a slope at whatever point I want it to be. Why isnt it working in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Now that I see, the main problem is with the learning rate. Learning rate of `0.01` is too high. Keeping it lower than `0.00035` works well. About `0.0002` works well and quick. I tried graphing things, and saw it made a lot of difference.

With a learning rate of `0.00035` and 1000 iterations, this was the graph:

[image]

With a learning rate of `0.0002` and 1000 iterations, this was the graph:

[image]

With a learning rate of `0.0004` and just `10` iterations, this was the graph:

[image]

Instead of converging to the point, its diverging. THat is why learning rate is important and anything bigger than 0.0004 will result in the same.

It took me quite some time to figure out.